# How to get removed a broken package (in this case "click")?

Tags: apt, uninstall

How to get removed broken package *click*? I'm trying install ubuntu-sdk in my 14.04 Ubuntu. I am getting too many errors.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove -f click
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Is read status information ... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
   click
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation released 166 ks of disk space.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 350824 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing click (0.4.38.5-0~457~ ubuntu14.04.1) ...
Trace Back (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/bin/click", line 31, in <module>
     from click import commands
Import Error: can not import name 'commands'
dpkg: error processing package click (--remove):
  subprocess command file pre-removal installed returned error exit status 1
Reading was too many errors:
  click
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg Returned an error code (1)
```

If im trying command `sudo apt-get purge -f`

Same errors happened.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After [that](https://askubuntu.com/a/613853/367165) was not successful, I have tested this "the hard way" ... and ... it works!

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/click
sudo apt-get autoremove -f click
```

The file has a problem when importing a Python module and you want to remove the package anyway. Therefore the file can be removed manually.

Comment: @A.B. Pretty bad advice since second command deletes a lot of system packages

Comment: This actually worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. However, I used `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install` after the two commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I had been trying to sort this out for 3 days!!

Answer (score 11):

i've had same error with broken packages **click** and **click-apparmor, url-dispatcher** after upgrading 14.04 -> 14.10 -> 15.04

*updated:

the solution for me was removing package folder `rm -rv /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/click`
and then:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f`

[solution source](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/click/+question/265998)

Comment: When you write "removing the package `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/click`", do you mean removing the file `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/click` or removing the package `click`

Comment: removing whole folder  manually :  `rm -rv /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/click` , because nothing of  `apt-get -f install` or `dpkg --reconfigure -a` , `apt-get autoremove -f click`  , `apt-get purge click` works.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get remove click
sudo pip3 uninstall click
sudo pip uninstall click
sudo apt-get install click -f
```

The problem is that many upgrade users will have a version of click installed with a version number under their pip or pip3 repository, these aren't managed by apt, and they take priority when Python's `import` keyword is invoked.

So, you need to uninstall them before reinstalling click is going to do you any good. The reasons they might be installed is that it can happen during setup of a third-party python app, and God knows I've done a few.

Comment: I'm just a reviewer: could you copy-paste all of the above in your actual answer before the system decides to delete your answer because of a lack of quality?  **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

Install *click* again to install the dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall click
```

Then remove it with this command.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove -f click
```

If that does not work, then install python and/or python3:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-click
```

and than again

```
sudo apt-get autoremove -f click
```

Comment: Nothing help, im get a same errors.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Try this three commands: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python;
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3;
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-click` and again `sudo apt-get autoremove -f click`

Comment: Nothing help.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 31, in <module>
    from click import commands
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands'
dpkg: error processing package click (--remove):

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -P click
```

or:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -r click
```

Comment: Package is totally broken, cannot install or unistall package.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I also had a python3 version of click installed through pip3. When I uninstalled the python3 version everything worked fine.